# C++ <istream> and <ostream>

Tags: c++

Hi I am currently studying c++ from a beginners book. In the book the author gives a brief explanation of both header files `istream` and `ostream`.  Unfortunately I don't quite understand what he means. I have tried to look them up online but it doesn't help me understand his explanation.

He says

> `istream`: Contains the extractors for inputting data from streams and includes the template class `basic_istream`. In other words, `istream` puts the I in I/O.
>
> `ostream`: Contains the inserters for outputting a series of bytes and includes the template `basic_istream`. basically `ostream` puts the O in I/O.

What I don't understand is why do you need extractors for inputting data from streams and vice-versa for the `ostream`.

Comment: Put them in `\`code blocks\``.

Comment: `istream` and `ostream` are helper classes to read/write contents from/to a stream. A stream can be the command line, a file, a network socket, whatever. Search for something like "java streaming IO" or "cin cout".

Comment: It all depends on the point of view, it's all relative. From the `istream`'s point of view, you extract the data from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data that serves as input to your program must be *extracted* from the `istream` that provides it.

Likewise, data that serves as output from your program must be *inserted* into the `ostream` that spirits it away.

```
+------------------+                  +-----------------------------------------+
| DATA SOURCE      |  ----input---->  | [istream] --extractor-->  YOUR PROGRAM  |
+------------------+                  +-----------------------------------------+

+------------------+                  +-----------------------------------------+
| DATA SINK        |  <---output----  | [ostream] <--inserter---  YOUR PROGRAM  |
+------------------+                  +-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I think I understand. istream is taking info from the object to put into my programs and ostream is the opposite correct?

Comment: @user3681722: Yes. "i" for "input" and "o" for "output", _from the point-of-view of your program_. From the point of view of the stream object, well you need to extract and insert with those streams respectively in order to make them work. The wording isn't contradictory, even if at first glance it may seem to be.

Comment: Thank you Orbit the diagram cleared it all up for me.

Answer (score 0):

> What I don't understand is why do you need extractors for inputting data from streams and vice-versa for the `ostream`.

Say you have `istream_obj` as input data stream. Now you write:

```
int x;
istream_obj>>x;
```

Here `istream` will try to extract an int from `istream_obj` with the overload like:

```
void operator >> (istream _stream, int x); // may not be exactly this but similar thing will be done.
```

This is what extraction from an istream means